# I am trying to implement bootstrap grids using flexbox and media query. During wrap the elements get extra spacing. How can I remove that?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I remove the extra space in the flex-wrap elements as shown in the
[image].
I have tried to wrap the column vertically when width becomes less than 900px and horizontally when it is greater than it.
My code is given below.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #528ef3;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
}

.items {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid darkblue;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .container {
        flex-wrap: wrap;

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Media Columns</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaColumn.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="items">This is column 1</div>
    <div class="items">This is column 2</div>
    <div class="items">This is column 3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not your codepen link with the code, that is just a picture.
You should also not base your question in just a link that could be broken in the future. It is better to share your code here and add the codepen link as an extra.

Comment: I have updated it. Thanks for your suggestions, it was my first question on stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `align-content: flex-start;`. Maybe you need to adjust some paddings and/or move the `align-content: flex-start;` in the media query.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #528ef3;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.items {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid darkblue;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .container {
        flex-wrap: wrap;

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Media Columns</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaColumn.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="items">This is column 1</div>
    <div class="items">This is column 2</div>
    <div class="items">This is column 3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My problem is not completely solved by the suggestion you have given.
I want the columns to be horizontally aligned when the screen is wider than 900px.
But following your code columns are not getting horizontal when screen is wide enough.
I am trying to achieve something similar in shorturl.at/hyMW5 this link

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry, I missunderstood your question then. I edited my answer, does it work for you now?

Comment: Yes its working now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To remove the unwanted space between the items you can change the `flex-direction: column;` property in your `.container` class (currently marked out) to `flex-direction: row;` and then in your media query add `flex-direction: column;`.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #528ef3;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.items {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid darkblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .container {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```